# How do I create a mySQL database to integrate with nodeJS on visual studio 2017 community?

Tags: mysql, node.js, visual-studio

The only progress I ever made on using my installation on VS was creating an sql file which doesn't help starting up a mySQL service from command line, which is exactly what I need right now. Given, the reputable sql book i learned from set up consists of launching the program from command line and creating tables in that fashion.

I only learned how to work with SQL on linux and it works flawlessly.

However I'm switching back to Windows. I have installed the necessary SQL packages yet I can't figure out how to set up my NodeJS HTTP server project to communicate with SQL.

I can't start the service on services.msc. And xaamp mySQL service isn't working either. I might even have lots of conflicting installations.

However, I'm asking about Visual Studio specifically. It gave me the option to install SQL packages during setup so I'm assuming I should be able to use it without paying Azure $200. That is, the online documentation which points me to Azure which my particular account doesn't seem to support from the online interface.

And VS is generally easy to set up. The only project I can create pertaining sql deals with sql files which I'm not to sure how to use and has no correlation with logging into a use and creating databases from command line as I'm used to with linux terminal.

Comment: Have you tried and failed to use the `mysql` package in npm? See this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql .  If you're hoping to run your node server behind IIS, you might investigate this. https://github.com/Azure/iisnode

Comment: @O.Jones That's right I can't even log in to a database using node API calls. The service isn't even running on my machine. If Visual Studio offers any command line based functionality to start a mySQL service I am not aware of that. I'm still looking into getting XAAMP built in mySQL service to work, which so far has no success. Then I also downloaded standalone third party SQL and added it to my path, had no success starting up the service. I was hoping Visual Studio SQL installation. However I don't know how to work with Visual studio aside from creating projects and writing some code.

Comment: Which service isn't running? The MySQL service? If it isn't running you have to install either the MySQL or MariaDB server install kit. (search for *Install MySQL on Windows*). If you install that kit, you'll have a working MySQL server. The stuff that comes with VS is Microsoft SQL Server. That's a different DBMS with a different dialect of SQL/

Comment: @O.Jones 
Concerning Miscrosoft SQL Server VS installation.
How do i start the service? and then access the SQL interface preferably from command line. To create users, databases, etc, your usual SQL commands.
As far as the IDE is concerned the only SQL functionality I have pulled out is generating an SQL file which is only used for commands.
I'm fairly confident I've installed the right packages.
It also looks like I have Azure installed as well, however accessing it from the website seems to indicate I need to pay for it. Yet i still have it installed on VS

Comment: That is, the mySQL service. As far as any built in server / data creation/ service instantiation built in within visual studio I have not tested since I just started using the IDE.

Comment: Microsoft always installs its Azure access stuff with VS: they're hoping to gain you as an Azure subscriber. If you want to use SQL Server, you need to install its developer edition along with VS.